# General solution to "Time and work" questions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If "a" number of machines can  complete a task in "x" days.
   "b" of them them could do the same task in "y" days.

how many days are required for "c" number of machines to do the same task?

example: 7 trucks can do the task in 4 days.
         3 trucks do it in  10 days.
         how many trucks are needed to do it in 5 days?

Comment: What? Is it the same task? Use your words!

Comment: Linear interpolation.

Comment: If it is the *same* task, ax = by = cz. Find z.

Comment: Instead of trying to find the number of days that it takes one machine to complete a single task, try to find the number of tasks that a machine can complete in on day. Ask yourself, "what is the difference between $days/task$ and $tasks/day$?". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_xZZt99MzY

Answer (score 1):

Increased machines and increased work per time per machine means decreased time, so
$$z = \frac{ax}c$$
For example, if it took $5$ machines $3$ days to complete a task, it would take $10$ machines
$$z=\frac{ax}c=\frac{(5)(3)}{(10)}=\frac{15}{10}=1\frac12 days$$
to complete that same task, assuming the relationship was proportional. Note that
$$ax=by=cz$$
However, the newly example provided example "7 trucks can do the task in 4 days. 3 trucks do it in 10 days. how many trucks are needed to do it in 5 days?" suggests that work per time is not proportional (varying efficiency?), so the machine-efficiency relationship would need to be known.